# Are there any existing datasets which can be used for Optical charatcer recognition?

Tags: dataset, data-science

Are there any existing data sets which can be used for Optical character recognition? Everywhere I search, what I get is handwritten characters.
I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Chars74K](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/demos/chars74k/) includes more than 74.000 images containing characters.
It contains 3,410 handdrawn characters, but also 7,705 characters obtained from natural images and 62,992 synthesised characters from computer fonts.

If you do not want to recognize single letters, but text in images, the [TC-11 datasets](http://tc11.cvc.uab.es/introduction/) could suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked. This dataset is pretty good:)